# Parsing data from EpicGames - Android Studio (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been trying to parse some data from *https://www.epicgames.com/store*.
I work in android studio (java).
This site does not use any json file. I need JavaScript to download data so I can't use Jsoup. Is there any possibility to parse list of games? In sources I have found something called "GraphQL". I were trying to apply it into my project, but this did not work (There was a failure when I were trying to Synchronize gradle). I tried with this tutorial https://android.jlelse.eu/implementing-apollo-client-in-android-studio-2d018fb36cd9

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Chrome:

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path of the exe file\chromedriver.exe");

// Initialize browser
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

// Open facebook
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");

// Maximize browser

driver.manage().window().maximize();

}

You have to download the right ChromeWebDriver and put it to the right place.
Here is a good tutorial:

> [Tutorial](http://learn-automation.com/launch-chrome-browser-using-selenium-webdriver/)

Hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

You could use a cloud module. Your server could use selenium (a WebDriver services), where you can see and download sources, textes and more. You have to use a server, because you can't use a device and the website will pop up in the foreground. After getting data with this amazing WebDriver, the server should upload the data to the cloud and and notify the devices to download the data.
 [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/)

You can get data very easy:

[Tutorial for getting picture from selenium](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCtg2rF1LSo)

Selenium is very easy to understand.

For an easy cloud connection, you can use firebase for free.

[Firebase](https://firebase.com)

Comment: Hi, I have downloaded Java files and I run simple code, but my app throws an exception. I guess the problem is with WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();. So I downloaded Chrome Web Driver, and I used WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, DesiredCapabilities.chrome()); - but this one also do not work. Do you have any ideas how to fix it?